# Any change to XAML or .proj makes VisualStudio 2013 take really long time to save and in not responding status

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, visual-studio-2013

Problem description: whenever I make any change to XAML file and save it, it takes at least half minute during which Visual Studio 2013 is totally not responding. Same thing happens when I try to load a .proj file, open or loand a solution (I understand it takes time to load a solution/project, but it takes longer than I experienced before). However, when I try to save a normal class file, it doesn't behave like that.

This problem has been existing for a while. My colleague told me it might be because I installed some unnecessary SW but it looks like I don't have those many extra SW anyway. Also when I check the task manager, I noticed that when this not-responding thing happens, the "Antimalware Service Executable" suddenly takes much system resource, more than 10% of the CPU. This I don't really understand. Why on earth the anti-malware service is suddenly running when saving the XAML/clearing the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I searched many posts tried some solutions. For example, I tried to open XAML file using XML editor, which doesn't show the designer (I suspected too that I had something to do with rendering my XAML) but it didn't help.

Then I found [this post](https://connect.microsoft.com/visualstudio/feedback/details/585430/vsip-visual-studio-builds-xaml-files-on-saving). In the "workarounds" section there is the solution works for me: exclude visual studio 2013 (devenv.exe) process from windows defender (the Antimalware Service Executable process) so it won't scan it when VS is apparently making a fuss so windows defender felt necessary to monitor that. This feels weird and I don't know what windows defender did (especially that I only tried to save a XAML file which essentially is a modification to one text file anyway).

Comment: I used SysInternals proc mon to watch Visual Studio while I was saving a XAML (an action that takes 5-10s on my very fast workstation).  I saw some odd things including:Loading lots of DLLs for UI controls (e.g. some Telerik controls, probably from XMLNS's like xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation"), and lots of registry actions for Microsoft Cryptography Provider keys

Comment: But the biggest culprit (8s of the 11s save) was the creation of a *.g.cs file for every single XAML file in my project!

Comment: @Trinition thank you for your info. 10s for saving XAML is a disaster. I was wondering how MS let this stupid problem persists for such basic/important operation.

Comment: I'm not sure if Visual Studio is doing the broad *.g.cs recreation on XAML save, or if maybe XAML Spy is.